# Laravel+Redis can retrieve key list but not a single key value

Tags: laravel, redis

I've a few counters in my redis db;

I can set from a console command and I can also be able to list keys

```
$key_names = Redis::keys("*api_count*");
```

In the same console command, dumping `$key_names` I got this

```
array:5 [
  0 => "dev_database_api_count_companies_2023_05_16"
  1 => "dev_database_api_count_check_last_event2023_05_16"
  2 => "dev_database_api_count_financial_2023_05_16"
  3 => "dev_database_api_count_check_last_event_2023_05_16"
  4 => "dev_database_api_count_authenticate_2023_05_16"
]
```

Then I try, in the same console command, to read a value

```
 $value = Redis::get('dev_database_api_count_companies_2023_05_16');
```

But I got a null

So I try usign redis-cli

```
127.0.0.1:6379> KEYS *
1) "dev_database_api_count_companies_2023_05_16"
2) "dev_database_api_count_check_last_event2023_05_16"
3) "dev_database_api_count_financial_2023_05_16"
4) "dev_database_api_count_check_last_event_2023_05_16"
5) "dev_database_api_count_authenticate_2023_05_16"
6) "dev_database_queues:default"
7) "dev_database_queues:default:notify"

127.0.0.1:6379> GET "dev_database_api_count_companies_2023_05_16"
"204"
```

What am I doing wrong?

Why `set` and `keys` works, but `get` no?

### Context

I am using Redis only as cache
I am using Laravel 8 for this specific project, but same behaviour it's in most recent Laravel 10

### Solved

Please see my own anser.
The problem was simply a matter of prefix.
I was ignoring that `keys` doesn't remove prefixes
But when using `get` I must omit prefixes

Comment: What's your Laravel version? And are you using Redis as cache? Or as database? Cause it can have different redis db? Try to change in env file REDIS_CACHE_DB=0 and get.

Comment: @fatm I added my own answer. I didn't know I should remove the prefix from names when calling. It was obbvious, after I learned, but wasn't so ovious to me before. sorry

Comment: Added context and information about my solution directly in the question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I understand now that `keys` doesn't remove the prefix added by laravel.

So when retrieving using `get` I must remove the prefix manually.

```
Redis::get(
  str_replace (config("database.redis.options.prefix"), "", $key_name)
);
```

I must not use

```
$value = Redis::get('dev_database_api_count_companies_2023_05_16');
```

But

```
$value = Redis::get('api_count_companies_2023_05_16');
```